# How to trust a user added certificate in Android?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I want to test a production app from android in a local network server with a self signed certificate. In order to do that in iOS I can add the certificate to the device and it will be trusted so I can use the app with that server.

When I add it using the Wifi->Advance->Install Certificate in most devices the app won´t work.

The only one where it works is a MIUI (Android 6.0.1) device which is rooted. Is it a requirement to be rooted to be able to trust a certificate?

Comment: I spent some time on this and I found out there is no way to apply certificates device wide in android. Check out my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

in AndroidManifest.xml add networkSecurityConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">




    </application>
</manifest>
```

in network_security_config add

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: IDE says "The Network Security Configuration allows the use of `user` certificates in the release version of your app", so it won't work for a debug version 

Comment: I used https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingDebugCa

Comment: @Konstantin I have a question is this count as absence of cerificate pinning.If I add this trust anchor?

Comment: @mikegrep sorry for miss your question but I dont understand it

Comment: Sorry if was not clear.My question was if I can use this technique to bypass certificate pining without remove the pinning itself  ut now I already know that even with this network configuration I can't bypass the certificate pinning in the app without actually remove it.

Answer (score 0):

#### To use self signed certificates you need to create a trust manager.

The trust manager handles the validation of certificates and that’s the part of the program that throws `SSLHandshakeException` when your server certificate is not signed by a trusted party.

Using a custom trust manager you have the ability choose which certificates are trusted and which are not, i.e. you can choose to trust or not to trust any certificate you like.

**The example below shows how to create a dummy `TrustManager` instance which trusts all certificates:**

```
public class SelfSignedCertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SelfSignedCertActivity";

    // Verifier that verifies all hosts
    private static final HostnameVerifier DUMMY_VERIFIER = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_self_signed_cert);
    }

    public void onOpenConnectionClick(View view) {

        new OpenConnectionTask().execute();
    }

    private class OpenConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Dummy trust manager that trusts all certificates
            TrustManager localTrustmanager = new X509TrustManager() {

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            };

            // Create SSLContext and set the socket factory as default
            try {
                SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{localTrustmanager},
                        new SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslc
                        .getSocketFactory());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Your Server URL goes here
                URL url = new URL("https://selfsigned.tanelikorri.com/");

                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setHostnameVerifier(DUMMY_VERIFIER);

                // Log the server response code
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.i(TAG, "Server responded with: " + responseCode);

                // And if the code was HTTP_OK then return true
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Hide progressbar
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (result != null) {

                // Create a dialog
                Builder builder = new Builder(SelfSignedCertActivity.this);
                if (result) {
                    builder.setMessage("Connection was opened successfully");
                } else {
                    builder.setMessage("Connection failed");
                }
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

                // and show it
                builder.create().show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

There is no way to add self signed server certificates at device level in Android. However you can trust such a self signed certificate in your application by creating your own Trust manager.

Check out this android doc link:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#SelfSigned

I also found a tutorial which shows how add self signed certificates to a browser in android (Chrome and Firefox), however it is still not applicable device wide and just that those applications enable you trust your certificates in them.

https://coderwall.com/p/wv6fpq/add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-android-for-browsing

Comment: I don't want to stop checking the authenticity of certificates inside the .apk, as I want to use the same app for production and test where the only difference is the server where the requests are made to. Therefore I just want to trust the certificate from the server inside the device, like I can do for example in iOS.

Comment: @nck I spent some time on this and I found out there is no way to apply certificates device wide in android. Check out my updated answer